# unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11" for GCC 4.8.1

Tags: c++11, mingw-w64

After reading a lot of literature on the internet, it seems that recent GCC versions definitely support the `-std=c++11` command line option. But for some crazy reason, I get the "unrecognized command line option" even when using GCC 4.8.1 which doesn't make any sense.

```
C:\newmingw\mingw32\bin>g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: [trimmed]
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project)

C:\newmingw\mingw32\bin>g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

Is there anything else that needs to be done here? TIA!

Comment: You might try compiling some C++ 11 code without the flag. At least some MinGW builds have enabled the `std=c++11` flag by default, so you don't have to do it explicitly.

Comment: Did you unpack a new version over an old version? Nuke the entire thing and unpack it fresh, it should be fine. If not, report a bug, because they packed wrong cc1plus or something.

Comment: Consider getting a new distro? Maybe one by mingw-builds.

Comment: Well, it's a trivial suggestion, but what does the documentation say about that option? What about `-std=c++0x`?

Comment: I have had weird issues with mingw on windows and c++11, just saying. I quickly escaped back to linux and I can happily cross compile from there.

Answer (score 1):

I am using mingw obtained via mingw-get from http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started
I can *not* confirm your problem. It might have something to do with your version being x64?

My version output is nearly identical:

```
C:\>g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: [...]
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
```

I am currently using this for a large project that uses a lot of the new c++11 functionalities.