# My MinGW-builds 32-bit installation won't recognize -std=c++11

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, mingw

I am utilizing Eclipse Kepler on a 64-bit Windows 7 system. I have attempted both an older version and the latest version of the MinGW-builds 32-bit installation, and neither seem to function properly in any regard, and more specifically don't even recognize any c++11 flags. I have attempted reinstalling multiple times to no avail. On the other hand, I can consistently get the 64-bit installation to work flawlessly. Trouble is, I want to work with some 32-bit libraries. Is there some extra step necessary for the 32-bit installation that I am unaware of? Thanks.

Note: I have tried all the suggestions on the somewhat related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120267/unrecognized-command-line-option-std-c11-for-gcc-4-8-1) (though it regards a different distro) and they did not work.

EDIT:

g++ --version output:

```
g++ (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Eclipse error:

```
20:20:45 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project workerbees ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-ID:\\blaise\\Dev\\libtcod-1.5.1\\include" -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o "src\\workerbees.o" "..\\src\\workerbees.cpp" 
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++11'

20:20:45 Build Finished (took 143ms)
```

Comment: What version? (check with `g++ -v`)

Comment: Post the error messages.

Comment: Sorry, version and exact error message is up.

Comment: Are you sure that Eclipse is picking up the same `g++` that's being used when you did the `g++ --version` command?  Maybe throw in a `--version` or `-v` option into the Eclipse project settings.

Answer (score 0):

As MinGW doesn't support POSIX API, it has to disable the C++11 thread related functionality in libstdc++ (because of absence of POSIX thread support).

However MinGW-W64 comes with toolchain targeting 32 bit Windows and better POSIX thread support. Follow steps as below to install MinGW-W64 with C++11 support:

- Download MinGW-W64 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/?source=typ_redirect) and extract it in some convenient location like C:\MinGW64 :

Ensure to download the appropriate package as in 
Files/ Toolchains targetting Win32 / Personal Builds / XXX / threads-posix / sjlj /

- Download MSYS binary for MinGW-W64 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/), extract in under C:\MinGW64\msys\
- Configure  MSYS to use MinGW by running c:\MinGW64\msys\1.0\msys.bat and typing:

  ```
      sh /postinstall/pi.sh
  ```

  Specify the MinGW installation location ( as in step 1) and you are ready to go.

Comment: Does a version of MinGW with gcc 4.8.1 disable c++11 support entirely because of problems with `<thread>` library support?

Comment: No, c++11 support is not disabled entirely. Only thread related functionality is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.8.1 certainly does support `--std=c++11`. You'll be able to see that for yourself by compiling a trivial program with version 4.8.1. The only reasonable conclusion therefore is that the compiler that does not recognise `--std=c++11` is an older version.